# Solr cross-domain ajax requests failing: API Plugin that gives access to HttpResponse headers?

Tags: json, solr

I could not make **cross-domain ajax-json** requests to my standalone solr server.

I was hoping to add the following snippet somewhere, but couldn't find it.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Is there any other workaround?

I've found the following link [SOLR-1944](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1944)

It is resolved by adding HttpRequest to the SolrRequest but not the response.

The user mentioned that he solved it by customizing **SolrDispatchFilter**, but couldn't figure out how.

Please could you guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using CORS (cross-origin resource sharing)for the same purpose. Following for worked for me.

```
public class DomainFilter implements Filter {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DomainFilter.class);


    public DomainFilter() {
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("Entering doFilter method------");
        HttpServletResponse responsee = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        responsee.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responsee.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        responsee.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
            "X-Requested-With,Host,Content-Type,User-Agent,Accept,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Charset,Keep-Alive,Connection,Referer,Origin");
        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        log.info("Exiting doFilter method------");
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

you will also need to add filter mapping in your web.xml.

```
<filter>
    <display-name>DomainFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>DomainFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mathworks.trdbsearch.search.DomainFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>DomainFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

This mapping takes care of any request coming from cross domain.

I hope thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Please could you clarify which 'web.xml' are you talking about? Is it Solr's?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the cross domain issue you just need to include json.wrf=? to the end of the solr query.

```
var queryurl = "http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=How+does+this+js+know%0A&wt=json&json.wrf=?"

$.getJSON(queryurl, function(results) {
    var totalPages = results.response.numFound;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question, but I just found a new easy answer in my searching.
In order to use CORS, one easy solution is to get JSONP file. What makes JSONP special is that it is wrapped in a function and the sever will assume it is a script. In this case, JSONP could ignore the CROS rule.

However, another problem is that Solr don't support to return JSONP directly. Fortunately, solr has a method in its JSON parser:

Official Doc [Link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON):

json.wrf=function - adds a wrapper-function around the JSON response, useful in AJAX with dynamic script tags for specifying a JavaScript callback function.

**In this case, what we need to do -- Simple Tree Steps**

1. Change the datatype to JSONP in ajax
2. Add "jsonCallback:'callback'" in ajax
3. At the end of query URL, add "json.wrf=callback"

A simple example:

```
var queryurl = "http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=How+does+this+js+know%0A&wt=json&json.wrf=callback&indent=true"
$.ajax({
  url: queryurl,
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType:'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'callback'
}).done(function(data) {
    mydata = data;
});
```

Then the data I return is stored in mydata varible. The data which we want is the response Object.

```
->mydata
Object {responseHeader: Object, response: Object}
->mydata["response"]
Object {numFound: 4916, start: 0, docs: Array[10]}
```